# Prolog Recursive Clause

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

I've got the following knowledge base, which is supposed to add two arguments and give the results:

```
add(0,X,X).
add(succ(X),Y,succ(R)):- add(X,Y,R).
```

Now this is my query:

```
?- add(succ(succ(succ(0))), succ(succ(0)), Result).
```

The 0 does not unify with the first argument so it goes to the second add/3 clause. Now here is the thing i can't figure out. The book (LPN) tells me that the outermost succ factor is stipped off the first argument, but I can't figure out why? In my mind it adds a succ functor. Could someone please explain why it is stripping it off?

Thanks in advance!

Luuk

Comment: Please add more details about that book. LPN is not enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this at your top level prompt:

```
?- succ(succ(0)) = succ(X).
```

Before you type `<Enter>`, what do you think the solution will be?

---

The "stripping" that the book talks about happens between the head of the second clause, `add(succ(X), ...)` and the recursive call `add(X, ...)`.

I don't really see the added value of talking about "stripping" here. What actually happens is that if the first argument to `add/3` is a term with the functor `succ/1` (so anything at all that looks like `succ(<Whatever>)`, then, `X` will be unified with this `<Whatever>`. In the case of the query:

```
?- add(succ(succ(succ(0))), succ(succ(0)), Result).
```

`<Whatever>` is `succ(succ(0))`, so the `X` is unified with `succ(succ(0))`, and this is the first argument to the recursive call to `add/3`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm finally able to see how it works thanks to the query you gave me!

Comment: `s(X)` for: "before you type enter"

Comment: @false Working hard for them `s(X)`s